# Is there a dereference_iterator in the STL?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I was wondering if there is an iterator in the STL that dereferences the object pointed before returning it. This could be very useful when manipulating containers aggregating pointers. Here's an example of what I would like to be able to do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int*> vec;

  int i = 1;
  int j = 2;
  int k = 3;

  vec.push_back(&i);
  vec.push_back(&j);
  vec.push_back(&k);

  copy(deref_iterator(vec.begin()), 
       deref_iterator(vec.end()), 
       ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); // prints "1 2 3"

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try Boost's [`indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html).

An `indirect_iterator` has the same category as the iterator it is wrapping. For example, an `indirect_iterator<int**>` is a random access iterator.

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for. Shame on me for not thinking about Boost :-)! However, I would have expected such an iterator to be present in the standard library...

Comment: Well, can more difficult problem be solved? I want to sort the vector of ptrs or partition it applying functions from <algorithms>. The problem here that I need to swap pointers in container whereas dereference to values of object.

Comment: @0x2207 it sounds like you want a custom comparison operator for your reference type. This operator will compare the dereferenced values. You can then pass this to `<algorithm>` you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

If it is impossible using Boost, writing a custom iterator is not that hard. Here is an example of a "dereference iterator" that meets the InputIterator requirements :

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
struct PointedType;

template <typename T>
struct PointedType<T*>
{
  typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename InputIterator>
struct DerefIterator
{
  typedef input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
  typedef typename PointedType<
            typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>::value_type
            value_type;
  typedef typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
            difference_type;
  typedef value_type* pointer;
  typedef value_type& reference;

  public:
    explicit DerefIterator(const InputIterator& ii)
      : it(ii) {}

    // Returns the object pointed by the object referenced by it
    reference operator*()  const { return **it; }
    pointer   operator->() const { return *it; }

    DerefIterator& operator++()
    {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }

    DerefIterator operator++(int)
    {
        DerefIterator tmp = *this;
        ++it;
        return tmp;
    }

    bool equals(const DerefIterator<InputIterator> & di) const
    {
        return di.it == it;
    }

  private:
    InputIterator it;
};

// Equality functions

template <typename InputIterator>
inline bool operator==(const DerefIterator<InputIterator>& di1, 
                       const DerefIterator<InputIterator>& di2)
{
  return di1.equals(di2);
}

template <typename InputIterator>
inline bool operator!=(const DerefIterator<InputIterator>& di1, 
                       const DerefIterator<InputIterator>& di2)
{
  return ! (di1 == di2);
}

//Helper function

template <typename InputIterator>
DerefIterator<InputIterator> deref_iterator(const InputIterator& ii)
{
  return DerefIterator<InputIterator>(ii);
}
```

Comment: You must use 'using namespace std;' for the above to compile.

Comment: @DavidDoria: A better approach is to prefix `input_iterator_tag` and `iterator_traits` with the `std` prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your actual use case is a bit more complex than a container of integer pointers!

You could check out the boost ptr containers
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html

The containers contain dynamically allocated objects (ie pointers).
But all access to the objects (direct or via iterator) returns a reference to the object.

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  boost::ptr_vector<int> vec;

  vec.push_back(new int(1));
  vec.push_back(new int(2));
  vec.push_back(new int(3));

  copy(vec.begin(),vec.end(),
       ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); // prints "1 2 3 "

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is fine if you want the container to have the ownership of the elements. indirect_iterator seems more appropriate when dealing with pointers to object with entity semantic which are already owned by something else (or allocated on the stack).