# how do I use STL algorithms with a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, stl, boost, lambda, c++11

I have a vector of pointers that are not owned by the container.  How do I use algorithms on the targets of the pointers.  I tried to use boost's ptr_vector, but it tries to delete the pointers when it goes out of scope.

Here is some code that needs to work:

```
vector<int*> myValues;
// ... myValues is populated
bool consistent = count(myValues.begin(), myValues.end(), myValues.front()) == myValues.size();
auto v = consistent ? myValues.front() : accumulate(myValues.begin(), myValues.end(), 0) / myValues.size();
fill(myValues.begin(), myValues.end(), v);
// etc.
```

I realize that for loops would work, but this happens in a bunch of places, so some kind of unary adapter?  I wasn't able to find one.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use features of the yet to be approved future C++ standard in your questions, you will limit the answers you get. It is very unclear if your question is about teh current standard library, the use of Boost, or the new features of C++0x.

Comment: It seems like v is supposed to be the average value of the ints, but then the copy line tries to copy to v, so v would have to be a pointer or iterator.

Comment: oh yeah, that last line was wrong... I meant to write "fill" instead of "copy".

Comment: Neil: Regarding the tags, I wasn't sure if the answer to my question would be available in the standard library (is it an adaptor?), boost (is it an iterator?), or C++0x (is it the new lambdas?).  However, you're right that the use of auto in my example code was probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [Boost Indirect Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html). When dereferenced (with `operator*()` ), it applies *an extra* dereference, so you end up with the value pointed by the pointer referenced by the iterator. For more information, you can also see [this question about a dereference iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352152/is-there-a-dereferenceiterator-in-the-stl).

Here's a simple example:

```
std::vector<int*> vec;

vec.push_back(new int(1));
vec.push_back(new int(2));

std::copy(boost::make_indirect_iterator(vec.begin()),
          boost::make_indirect_iterator(vec.end()),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));     // Prints 1 2
```

Comment: oh, nice, that was your question -- way to pass on the knowledge ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
bool consistent = count_if(myValues.begin(), myValues.end(), 
   bind2nd(ptr_fun(compare_ptr), *myValues.front())) == myValues.size();

int v = consistent ? *myValues.front() : accumulate(
   myValues.begin(), myValues.end(), 0, sum_int_ptr) / myValues.size();

for_each(myValues.begin(), myValues.end(), bind1st(ptr_fun(assign_ptr),v));
```

Fill can't take assign function (so that it would dereference pointers). Therefore for_each() was used. For optimization it would be wise to add if(!consistent) before running for_each(). Functions used in above STL one liners:

```
int sum_int_ptr(int total, int * a) { return total + *a; }    
void assign_ptr(int v, int *ptr) { *ptr = v; }    
bool compare_ptr(int* a, int pattern) { return *a == pattern; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot from your reply.  I will probably go with the boost indirect iterators here, but it's nice to know how how to use bind1st, bind2nd, and so on.

Comment: yeah STL is quite powerful, it is worth knowing all these one-liners like accumulate, etc.

Comment: PS.: Worth reading: http://www.keithschwarz.com/cs106l/fall2007/handouts/200_STL_Functional_Library.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can look at `boost::shared_ptr<>` - a smart pointer with reference counting. It will not delete the pointer after it goes out of scope.

Comment: the problem is that the pointers are to member variable in other objects.  I could make those into shared_ptr too, but that might not be the most efficient way to do this.