# Using C++ std::equal on a container of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, equality, stl-algorithm

I have a container of std::shared_ptr.  I want to compare two containers using std::equal.  The class A has operator== defined.  I want equal to compare if each element is equivalent using its operator==, not the one defined in shared_ptr.

Do I need to make a function or function object to pass to equal?  Or is there something built-in that would be simpler (like something defined in <functional>)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need a function or a function object or a lambda expression (since you're able to use `std::shared_ptr`, you have some part of C++0x already enabled).

There is nothing in `<functional>` to help you, but there is something in boost: the [indirect iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>
int main()
{
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> v1;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> v2;
        v1.emplace_back( new int(1) );
        v2.emplace_back( new int(1) );

        bool result =
            std::equal( boost::make_indirect_iterator(v1.begin()),
                        boost::make_indirect_iterator(v1.end()),
                        boost::make_indirect_iterator(v2.begin()));
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << result << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I've been avoiding adding a boost dependency.  Too bad that's exactly what I want...

Comment: @Matt: you can always write your own dereference iterator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352152/is-there-a-dereference-iterator-in-the-stl/352162#352162

Comment: Cool, I think I'll still use the function object because it's simple in this case, but that's an interesting idea if I need similar functionality more after this.

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like the following, assuming you have a compiler that supports lambdas and that no items are ever null:

```
bool CompareA(const vector<shared_ptr<A>>& first, 
              const vector<shared_ptr<A>>& second) {

   return equal(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(),
              [](const shared_ptr<A>& item1, const shared_ptr<A>& item2) -> bool{
                   return (*item1 == *item2);
               });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's better to pass `shared_ptr`'s by const reference, since copying them is a bit expensive.

Comment: @Cubbi True, it also unnecessarily incremented the reference count as well. Changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally thinking the function object would be the best bet ... everything that I've seen in `<functional>` depends on having the correct comparison type, and that would mean if you didn't want to compare the pointers themselves, that you would somehow need a dereference of those pointers to the objects they're pointing to ... I don't see any helpers in the STL that automatically do that dereference for you.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted, I didn't think it existed either but maybe I missed something.